# Graphql schema explorer

Tags: postman

I have started using postman for my graphql queries (using Altair so far). While I do get autosuggest in query, I do not see any option to explore loaded schema. All other graphql api tools have that options. Can someone please help?

Switching because postman has better option to manage environment and headers.

Comment: if you get autocomplete, don't you see the API schema under the tab APIs on the left hand bar?

Comment: @bitoiu No. I only see REST api I imported.

Comment: How did you import it?

Comment: @bitoiu It is AutoFetched feature of postman. I have graphql server url which has interospection enabled.

Comment: It is not supported. There is already a ask - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11041